# MVC 5 ASP.NET dynamic getter and setter in Model definition

Tags: c#, model, asp.net-mvc-5

If I have model as shown below.  When does the TruncatedMetaDescription get committed in database?  Is it always recreated when the page is accessed or only when the data row  is been created?

```
[Display(Name = "Content")]
public string ArticleText { get; set; } 
public string TruncatedMetaDescription
{
 get
 {
  return this.ArticleText.Length > 160 ? this.ArticleText.Substring(0, 160) + "..." : this.ArticleText;
  }
  set
   {
     ;
    }
  }
```

I have a feeling this is redone everytime the page is assessed hence impacting on the performance of the page.  Please advice is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: I couldn't get you by saying "When does the TruncatedMetaDescription get committed in database"? Are you using Code First Approach in your application

Comment: Put a debug stop on in the get or set, and see that happens...:)

Comment: thanks for this  @RitchieD  this is very bad - the page breaks uncountable number of times can you suggest how I can achieve this same thing differently